# remove first folder in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have some URLs like:

```
http://example.com/username/file.zip
http://example.com/username/videos/aaa.avi
http://example.com/username/videos/abc/asdfdef/aaa.avi
```

the real path of files are:

```
/file.zip
/videos/aaa.avi
/videos/abc/asdfdef/aaa.avi
```

so basically I need to remove first folder in the URL
I tried to use this rewrite rule :

```
rewrite ^/.*/(.*)$ /$1 last;
```

but its remove all folders and grep just the filename, it's work just for first URL and i get 404 error for rest of them

**- P.S: the username could be anything**

Answer (score 1):

i didnt test it but based on that nginx uses pcre library i think

`rewrite ^/.*?/(.*)$ /$1 last;`

would work.

`.*?` matches any character between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)